# My jquery - ajax request is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to delete images in a table using ajax. This image table is generating dynamically using php. I use Bootstrap modal to conform before delete the image.

This is my Jquery -

```
// Display confirmation dialog  
$('td a.delete-slideshow-image').click(function(e) {
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
    if (!$('#deleteSlideshowConfirmation').length) {
        $('body').append('<div id="deleteSlideshowConfirmation" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">'+
                                                        '<div class="modal-dialog">'+
                                                                '<div class="modal-content">'+
                                                                        '<div class="modal-header">'+
                                                                                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                                                                                '<h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>'+
                                                                        '</div>'+
                                                                        '<div class="modal-body"></div>'+
                                                                        '<div class="modal-footer">'+
                                                                                '<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>'+
                                                                                '<a class="btn btn-primary slideshowConfirmOk" id="'+imageId+'">Delete</a>'+
                                                                        '</div>'+
                                                                '</div>'+
                                                        '</div>'+
                                                '</div>');
    }

    $('#deleteSlideshowConfirmation').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));

    $( "a.slideshowConfirmOk" ).click(function() {  
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var data = 'imageId=' + id ;
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

        alert(data);

        $.ajax(
        {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "delete_row.php",
                 data: data,
                 cache: false,

                 success: function()
                 {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                 }
         });
    });

    $('#deleteSlideshowConfirmation').modal({show:true});
    return false;   

e.preventDefault();
});
```

My problem is when I conform to delete its not changing image id. If it need to change I want to refresh my page.

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this code. 
Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: This is how my `HTML` rendering -http://pastebin.com/S7HS2s8x

Comment: You should use `bootbox.js`, you then would be able to do something as simple as `bootbox.confirm('You sure?', function(r) { if(r) { $.ajax(); } });`. http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: You should also separate the two `click` handlers from eachother. Not put the second one inside the first one.

Comment: Finally, what do you mean by `its not changing image id`? Where? Which `image id` What is `it`?

Comment: it alert same id = alert(data);

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: How come the ID would change? Shouldn't be the same both on the delete `button` and on the modal confirm `button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
    // Display confirmation dialog  
    $('td a.delete-slideshow-image').click(function (e) {
        window.tr = $(this).parents('tr'); // store the 'TR' in a global variable, no need for the keyword 'var'
        var imageId = $(this).data('id'); // use data-id='$image_id' in your HTML table
        var modal = '<div id="deleteSlideshowConfirmation" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">' + 
            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body"></div>' +
            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>' +
            '<a class="btn btn-primary slideshowConfirmOk" data-id="' + imageId + '">Delete</a>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'; // put your modal content in a variable


        $(modal).find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));

        $(modal).modal({ // then use jQuery selector on that variable to make it show, no need for appending to the body
            show: true
        });
        return false;

        e.preventDefault();
    });
    // separate the two click handlers
    $(document).on('click', 'a.slideshowConfirmOk', function () { // use $(document) to dyanmically bind the event on your confirm button
            var id = $(this).data('id'); // use data-id="'+imageId+'" in your modal
            var data = 'imageId=' + id;
            // var parent = $(this).parents('tr'); << this is useless now

            console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_row.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,

                success: function () {
                    $('#deleteSlideshowConfirmation.modal').modal('hide'); // hide modal on ajax success
                    window.tr.fadeOut('slow', function () { // use the global variable here to fade it out
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

How this works for you?

Comment: Every thing seems to be good. But one question, this line `var parent = $(this).parent().parent();` is not select my table `tr`.

Comment: Maybe use `$(this).parents('tr');` to target your `tr`?

Comment: I changed my code like this -` //var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            var parent = $(this).parents('tr');

Comment: Great. Glad it worked! Feel free to accept my answer if it suited your requirements.

Comment: What do you mean by `table row is not selecting`? Selecting what?

Comment: I edited my answer. Store the `tr` in a global variable and use it to fade it out.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are generating table dynamically so what is happening over there. Jquery ready function bind the events on elements after DOM loaded, in your case it could not bind event on your target elements. Try to change the syntax of click event like as below.

```
$(document).on('click','td a.delete-slideshow-image', function(e) {

//Your code

})
```

And in your ajax call

```
$( document ).on('click',"a.slideshowConfirmOk", function() {  
//AJAX code
})
```

Main key thing is bind your events on document when you're working on elements dynamically. 
I assume you've included jquery's latest version.

Comment: The table is generated dynamically but with PHP. So it's already here when the DOM is loaded. No need for using the syntax you provided.